How to execute a script in Clickhouse from Linux CLI?
This may seem to be an easy question, but I did not find an answer, despite searching for it for a while and my attempts did not succeed.
I'm running Sentry via Docker and it uses Clickhouse. I can connect to the container where clickhouse is located via
docker exec -it $(docker ps -aqf 'name=sentry-self-hosted_clickhouse_1') bash

And there I can connect to clickhouse-client and execute commands there. For the sake of simplicity, let's assume that the command I am to run is as simple as
SELECT 1 + 2;

I have tested it and it correctly returned 3, just as expected, as the attached image also shows:

Now, what I would like to do is to run this script from outside the Docker container and output the results in the terminal (my actual goal is to create a programmatic backup system for Sentry, of which Clickhouse backup is also a part of, but asking for that would be too vague and I decided to instead ask about my main obstacle, that is, executing a script from outside of clickhouse-client). This is how I can connect to Clickhouse from outside the container:
Surely I can connect to the Docker container via clickhouse-client directly too, like
docker exec -it $(docker ps -aqf 'name=sentry-self-hosted_clickhouse_1') clickhouse-client -u <myusername> --password <mypassword>

and so my stuff afterwards. But, what I would like to have instead is something like this (of course, the command is incorrect):
docker exec -it $(docker ps -aqf 'name=sentry-self-hosted_clickhouse_1') clickhouse-client -u <myusername> --password <mypassword> -e "SELECT 1 + 2;"

(this -e was inspired of how MySQL allows me to execute commands inline like this)
or even better:
cat myinput.sql | docker exec $(docker ps -aqf 'name=sentry-self-hosted_clickhouse_1') clickhouse-client -u <myusername> --password <mypassword> > myoutput.sql

How can I achieve this? (I have searched for possible solutions, without much luck, either I am missing something obvious, or this is not well-documented)

To run a query passed as argument:
$ docker compose exec clickhouse clickhouse-client -q 'select 1 + 2'
   ┌─plus(1, 2)─┐
1. │          3 │
   └────────────┘

To run a query piped in:
$ echo 'select 1 + 2' | docker compose exec -T clickhouse clickhouse-client
3

These work with my Docker Compose setup. To run these with your plain Docker setup, the following should work:
$ docker exec -it $(docker ps -aqf 'name=sentry-self-hosted_clickhouse_1') clickhouse-client -u <myusername> --password <mypassword> -q 'select 1 + 2'

and
$ echo 'select 1 + 2' | docker exec -i $(docker ps -aqf 'name=sentry-self-hosted_clickhouse_1') clickhouse-client -u <myusername> --password <mypassword>

(Note I removed -t and only kept -i, see this.)

i was about to answer but this is the best answer i assume, waiting for OP to accept

Thanks for the answer! I have managed to make the first example work via docker exec $(docker ps -aqf 'name=sentry-self-hosted_clickhouse_1') clickhouse-client -u <myusername> --password <mypassword> -q "SELECT 1 + 2" but the second example did not work, tried with echo "SELECT 1 + 2" | docker exec -T $(docker ps -aqf 'name=sentry-self-hosted_clickhouse_1') clickhouse-client -u <myusername> --password <mypassword>. It does not recognize the T and says "unknown shorthand flag: 'T' in -T" unfortunately. I noticed you run docker compose exec instead of docker exec though

The way I was able to make it work is via foobar=cat mysql.sql and then docker exec $(docker ps -aqf 'name=sentry-self-hosted_clickhouse_1') clickhouse-client -u <myusername> --password <mypassword> -q "$foobar" but I worry about the possibility that mysql.sql may contain newlines and other stuff and whether it is safe to embed this into a variable without having the danger of crashes or the like

@LajosArpad Note the last line of the answer: with docker exec, you don't need -it or -T. Let me know if that works.

It yields Code: 62. DB::Exception: Empty query, unfortunately. The command looks like echo "select 1 + 2" | docker exec $(docker ps -aqf 'name=sentry-self-hosted_clickhouse_1') clickhouse-client -u <myusername> --password <mypassword>

@LajosArpad please see my updated answer, I just tested and docker exec -i works (only need to remove -t).

Indeed, you are right. Thanks!  It works both with echo "select 1 + 2" | ... and cat somefile.sql | .... My current problem is that the way its documentation (at https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/backup) claims to enable the backup does not work (I get a syntax error). But it's unrelated to this question and consequently I'm gratefully accepting your answer.

@LajosArpad great! Regarding the backup problem, you should post another question with full details to replicate the problem and hopefully someone would help.

Sure thing, but first I need to exhaust the possibility basic research, so if I figure it out, then I will either not ask a question or self-answer one. Thanks so much for the help you have provided.
